# What is the difference between windows desktop apps and windows store apps

Tags: windows, windows-8

I read few posts online but I have not understood what is the difference between them. Could anybody please clarify ?

Comment: The question "What do they have in common?" is much easier to answer: nothing.

Comment: @HansPassant It seems you know the answer. Kindly explain.

Answer (score 1):

Many of these answers are wrong.  Actually, the question itself is slightly wrong.

The two kinds of app are Desktop Apps and Modern UI Apps (what used to be called Metro apps.)  Both kinds can go into Store.

Desktop Apps look like the old kind.  They aren't fullscreen, they run in the desktop area, they don't have to have a user interface (so services are desktop apps,) et cetera.

Modern UI Apps are the new kind.  They're fullscreen and snap, blah blah.

Modern UI Apps have a lot of new requirements.  They have to declare what file types they handle.  They aren't allowed to save as *.  Some obscurer older APIs are shut off for them, which can be a problem for people trans-compiling from older languages.  They aren't allowed to declare the quiet read flag for the documents folder.

But practically speaking, you aren't going to see a whole lot of difference between the two, unless you're doing weird stuff, other than the fullscreen-vs-windowed bit.

Non-commercial accounts aren't allowed to use the desktop UI.

Comment: Desktop apps cannot be sold via the Windows Store.  See section 3.1 at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx

Comment: You have confused "Desktop applications", which are Windows 8 .appx applications, with "Local desktop applications," which are Win32/Win64 .exe s.

Section 3.1 does not forbid desktop applications from store; rather, it forbids store applications from relying on non-store applications.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/06/08/listing-your-desktop-app-in-the-store.aspx

You can find the example project "Contoso File Wizard" in the sample set to see how it's done.

It's unfortunate that this question was closed.  It's quite germane.

Comment: Alternately, please explain why there's a "metro" and a "desktop" tab at the top of your Store panel, or why they take the time to tell you that you have to have a commercial (not personal) account to submit desktop applications, if store can't list desktop applications.

Comment: With respect, this is something you can test yourself, if you'd like to.  "Local desktop application" is the .exe.  "Desktop application" is a .appx; if you have a commercial account, just make one, then go to compile it, and you will receive a .appxupload.

Comment: You can confirm that RT can run Desktop applications by going to the desktop and starting the Desktop UI version of IE, or Office, or installing the Contoso File Wizard from store.  Whether any given individual desktop application can target RT is a question of whether that developer included an RT binary; by default C# and JS projects do, but C++ takes a little extra effort.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19127/discussion-between-harry-johnston-and-john-haugeland)

Comment: They have made this so insanely confusing. According to this URL: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt637083%28v=vs.85%29.aspx desktop apps can be sold in the store, but I've yet to see a non-Metro'y app in the Store.  Like 7-zip or Notepad++ - they don't exist.  What is wrong with MS? Come up with something a little more descriptive please!!

Answer (score 0):

Windows Store Apps are designed to work in the "Metro" interface and will run on both Windows RT (tablet and laptop) and Windows 8 Pro. 
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974576.aspx.

Windows Desktop Apps are the traditional applications that we have been building until now. This apps will not work on tablets.

Comment: what is the difference between their functionality ? I mean can each type do what other can ? or what are the limitations of each ?

Comment: The topic is far too broad for StackOverflow. It's like asking for a description of the difference between OSX and iOS.

Comment: As much as I love The Old New Thing, I must strongly disagree with you here.  Asking what the limitations and differences are between the two types of .appx that file into Win8 Store are does not actually bear up comparison with two unrelated operating systems.

There are valid constraints on Metro apps that will be germane to developers (some which don't make any sense, like an app's complete inability to self-screenshot.)

Questions like this should not be shut down.

Comment: "This apps will not work on tablets."   well they do!

Answer (score 0):

**Windows 8 Desktop Application:** That just the basic program like notepad, MS Word, AutoCad... Writing in the know language such as C++, C#, VB ...

**Windows 8 Store App** Here you create app in that new start menu. Click on the button in the start menu to open your own app. Here you can write the app also in html5/javascript or c#.

Comment: let me say a few things based on my understanding, kindly tell if I am right/wrong.   1) tweetdeck is desktop app                     2) desktop app can create folder and app shortcuts while store apps cannot.                                                             3) desktop app can be started on windows start but not store apps

Comment: a desktop app is that have  - [] x   on the top right. And Windows Store have that not, but use the swipe down to close the app.
1. ok
2. in the metro app (if the developer use that API)
3. you can open in the 'start menu' you desktop app or metro app